# How to pass mongodb ObjectId() in HTTP request JSON body?

Tags: json, node.js, mongodb, rest, express

I need to send a mongo query in JSON typed request body, something like:

```
{ _id : { $gt : ObjectId("575d0c22964ddb3b6ba41bed") } }
```

(to get records inserted later than the id'ed record)

On the node server side I have express with body-parser middleware. It won't parse the request body JSON unless everything is quoted. E.g. the above has to be like:

```
{ "_id" : { "$gt" : "ObjectId(\"575d0c22964ddb3b6ba41bed\")" } }
```

The db runs the query with all the quotation marks and returns nothing.

How do I pass `ObjectId()` to `mongodb` as a function without re-parsing the whole request body and stripping off the quotation marks?

I'm testing with postman extension in Chrome, and sends the request to a REST `url: /api/:obj_type/list`.

The entire request body is used as a query.

Answer (score 1):

you would be only passing around the string value in the client and server until a request is made the the database at which point you would make it a new ObjectID with the same value to be passed into the db. Passing around a string is a bit easier as all the clients/server know how to deal with a string vs ObjectID - also passing the ObjectID in a URL would be an issue. - To answer your question on how to pass the ObjectID() to Monogdb without re-parsing. You really wouldn't unless I'm misunderstanding the context

but pass around the ID as a string so it would be something like var `stringId = "507f1f77bcf86cd799439011"` and when you are about do a query you would do something along the lines of `col.find({_id: new ObjectId(stringId)}).toArray(function(err,results){});`

Comment: Thanks @Andrei M. I already have a route definition   app/api/:obj_type/read/:id    that handles get one by id. Here I'm trying to pass a complex query in request body to a more generic path: app/api/:obj_type/       And the problem is how to keep the server side code as generic and clean as possible.